# Рисовать на виджете

Tags: java, android

Ребят! Кто сталкивался с таким? Как можно реализовать рисование на канве на виджете, извиняюсь за каламбур. Задание как бы нарисовать линию на виджете, я пытался сделать дедовским способом, создал вьюху и на ней нарисовал, но вставить в виджет такое не получается, нужен другой способ.

**UPD**:

Нашел один блог, на котором [описано как рисовать](http://madandroid.blogspot.com/2011/05/drawing-on-widget-canvas.html?showComment=1332934455505#c6163602352475204016) на виджете, но там не весь код, и непонятно, куда его писать. Я написал в классе наследнике `AppWidgetProvider`, в методе `onUpdate()`, но ничего не изменилось, рисунка нет...

**UPD2:**

Поискал по стековерфлов похожие вопросы набрел на один и переделал под себя, так же не работает, может кто-то исправит меня. Вот как я седлал:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(16);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

    Bitmap mybitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 16, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(mybitmap);

    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    c.drawText("fdgfdgfdgfdfdfdgGFDFGFDDDDG", 0, 0, paint);

    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, mybitmap);  
}
```

Что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new View(context) {
    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
      super.onDraw(canvas); 
      // ваши манипуляции с канвасом
    } 
}
```

И не забудьте переопределить метод `onMeasure`.

Comment: Я так понимаю это мне писать в метод onUpdate() ?

Переопределить метод каким образом? onMeasure() { super.onMeasure(); } ?

Comment: А как мне потом сделать что бы этот вью рисовал? В мейн.xml как прописать? или где?

Comment: Так вы переопределили метод onDraw или нет?

Comment: так переопределять onMeasure() иди onDraw()?

И что вы подразумеваете под переопределить? Унаследовать класс вью? и с его помощью передать онДрав в класс виджета?

Comment: Да, класс нужно унаследовать от View. В вашем случае этой вью скорее всего будет AppWidgetHostView, но это вам надо самим определить, от какого класса вы хотите наследоваться.
Переопределять нужно и onDraw, и onMeasure. Вы спрашивали в какое место вставить код рисования, я вам указал - в метод onDraw. Но при этом onMeasure тоже нужно переопределить, чтобы вьюшка выставляла себе правильные размеры.

Comment: Что-то я ничего не понял, как это AppWidgetHostView будет моей View ? В классе AppWidgetHostView нету метода onDraw() и его переопределить ну никак не получится. И вот еще вопрос как понимать - " Вы спрашивали в какое место вставить код рисования, я вам указал - в метод onDraw." ? Как я его напишу в онДрав когда его у меня нет, он есть токо в классе вью?